# 'linux-generic-hwe-18.04' not found after upgrade to 18.04

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, hardware-enablement-stack

Since upgrading to 18.04 from 16.04 I have been seeing the following message:

```
➜  ~ hwe-support-status 

You have packages from the Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) installed that
are going out of support on 2023-04-30.

To upgrade to a supported (or longer-supported) configuration:

* Upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS by running:
sudo do-release-upgrade -p

OR

* Switch to the current security-supported stack by running:
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-hwe-18.04

and reboot your system.
➜  ~ hwe-support-status --show-all-unsupported
➜  ~ hwe-support-status --show-replacements
linux-generic-hwe-18.04
➜  ~ sudo apt-get install linux-generic-hwe-18.04
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-generic-hwe-18.04
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-generic-hwe-18.04'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-generic-hwe-18.04'
➜  ~ sudo do-release-upgrade -p
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found.
➜  ~ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
➜  ~
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: There is [no such package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=linux-generic-hwe-18.04) in Ubuntu repositories now. It is very likely that it will be created later as [`linux-generic-hwe-16.04`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=linux-generic-hwe&searchon=names). See [this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Kernel.2FSupport.A18.04.x_Ubuntu_Kernel_Support).

Comment: Can this basically be ignored then?

Comment: You probably have some version of the hwe kernel package installed - very likely if you did the hwe update in 16.04.  If you did an `apt policy linux-generic*` you could see what kind of kernel packages you have installed.  Likely you could just remove the offending hwe package then, as long as you have another kernel package installed, of course.

Comment: Fixed! Thanks to Organic Marbles reply :) "apt policy linux-generic" showed I had "linux-generic-lts-vivid" installed, I removed this but was still getting the warning. I then altered the hwe-support-status script so it actually told me which package was unsupported and discovered I also had "linux-headers-generic-lts-vivid" installed (in hindsight, I should have ran apt autoremove after removing the old kernel).

Answer (score 4):

No specific hwe or lts linux-image is yet required for 18.04 (so it doesn't exists). Ensure first that linux-image-generic image is installed:

```
 apt install linux-image-generic
```

Then remove old hwe or lts linux images, in my case I did:

```
apt purge linux-image-generic-lts-xenial
```

Then the `hwe-support-status` command returns a clean empty response.

Comment: I had to use `aptitude` to identify and purge the old, unused `*-lts-*` images. After doing it, everithing is OK.

Answer (score 2):

I had an old unsupported Linux kernel installed, discovered using

```
# apt policy linux-generic\*
```

Remember to run

```
# apt autoremove
```

to remove any unused dependencies which may also be picked up by hwe-support-status.